# Doctrine2 how to create the query builder using the named query?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I can use the `@NamedQuery` annotation to create the Query, but not QueryBuilder.
How to create the QueryBuilder from the Named Query to add an additional `where` statements, without parsing the query string?

Comment: what difference would it be with putting the query builder in the repository of the class?

Comment: I already have some named queries in Entity annotation and I don't want to split the named queries between Entity and Repo - some named queries in the Entity Annotation, some named queries in the Repo. I just want a list of named queries in the Entity Annotations only